# Deleting structure in C programming

Tags: c, structure

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct {
    char serie_calculator[45];
    char tip_procesor[78];
    char memorie[55];
    char hdd[60];
    char monitor[65];
}Calculator;

void deleting(Calculator *ct, int *dim, char serie[45])
{
    int k = 0, i, j;
    for (i = 0;i<(*dim);i++)
        if (strcmp((ct + i)->serie_calculator, serie) == 0)
        {
            k++;
            for (j = i;j < (*dim - k);j++)

                *(ct + j) = ct[j + 1]; // <== This line here

        }
    *dim = *dim - k;
}
```

In the `deleting` function, I don't understand what the line: `*(ct + j) = ct[j + 1];` does. Can somebody help? I hope that you understand the function, because this is just a sequence from the whole program.

Comment: When marking out special lines in the code, please do it with comments. Formatting doesn't work in code blocks.

Comment: Also, remember that for any pointer or array `p` and index `i` the expressions `p[i]` and `*(p + i)` are equal. Now thing a little about that, and what it means for something like `*(ct + j) = ct[j + 1]`. I recommend you first translate `*(ct + j)` to it's equivalent `ct[j]`. And learn how to use a debugger, then you can step through the line by line while monitoring variables and their values, to see what's happening.

Comment: @Andrei Popescu  It is unimportant what this line does because the function is invalid in whole.:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this function

```
void deleting(Calculator *ct, int *dim, char serie[45])
```

it seems that the first parameter is declared like a pointer to the first element of the array passed to the function as an argument.

Thus

```
ct[0]
```

will denote the first element of the array

```
ct[1]
```

will denote the second element of the array and so on.

This record

```
ct[i]
```

where i is some index is equivalent to

```
*( ct + i )
```

So this statement

```
*(ct + j) = ct[j + 1];
```

can be written also like

```
ct[j] = ct[j + 1];
```

As for the function itself then it is entirely wrong.

In this loop

```
        for (j = i;j < (*dim - k);j++)

            *(ct + j) = ct[j + 1]; // <== This line here
```

that as it was said can be written also like

```
        for (j = i;j < (*dim - k);j++)

            ct[j] = ct[j + 1]; // <== This line here
```

there is an attempt to write beyond the array  when j is equal to `*dim - 1` because expression `j + 1` in this case will be equal to `*dim` though the valid range of indices is `[0, *dim - 1]`

Also the condition in the outer loop also should look at least like

```
for (i = 0; i < (*dim) - k; i++)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

and the index `i` shall not be increased when an element of the array was deleted. Otherwise the next element after the deleted element will be skipped.

A correct implementation of the function that I named like `remove_all` can look the following way as it is shown in the demonstrative program below. I simplified the structure declaration because other data members of the structure are irrelevant for the function implementation.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct 
{
    char serie_calculator[45];
    // ...    
} Calculator;

size_t remove_all( Calculator c[], size_t n, const char *s )
{
    size_t i = 0;

    for ( size_t j = 0; j < n; j++ )
    {
        if ( !( strcmp( c[j].serie_calculator, s ) == 0 ) )
        {
            if ( i != j ) c[i] = c[j];
            ++i;
        }
    }

    return i;
}

int main(void) 
{
    Calculator c[] = { { "A" }, { "B" }, { "C" }, { "A" }, { "D" }, { "E" }, { "A" } };
    const size_t N = sizeof( c ) / sizeof( *c );

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ ) printf( "%s ", c[i].serie_calculator );
    printf( "\n" );

    size_t n = remove_all( c, N, "A" );

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ ) printf( "%s ", c[i].serie_calculator );
    printf( "\n" );

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
A B C A D E A 
B C D E
```